# PC occasionally loses wired LAN connection

Tags: windows-10, networking, lan, desktop-computer

My windows 10 PC is occasionally losing the wired LAN connection.
During those times, the internet does not work and I cannot even reach the gateway:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

After some time the problem usually normalizes and everything works again.
Other machines in the same network are not affected.

Still this is a very frustrating issue to have.
How can I best diagnose what is causing the issue and fix it?

Comment: Would it be easy to try a different network cable? You could also try a different port on the switch. Is the computer dusty inside? That could lead to some components overheating.

Comment: The computer is not dusty inside. I just changed the LAN cable to a completely new one, attached it to a different LAN port in the switch and the issue is still happening.

Comment: At this point, it could be anything and there is no definite answer on how to fix it. Try to isolate the problem appropriately to your available options (connect a different computer to the cable, change the cable, etc.). Can you reach the router with a different device **while the connection is not working**?

Comment: Please provide a network schematic including IP configurations of the router and all end nodes connected.

Comment: Yes, other devices can reach the router without issues at all times. I re-installed all network related drivers and then I noticed ZeroTier which was running on this machine. When it is turned off, the problem disappears so it seems to be related. I don't understand why this would be an issue since the whole internet breaks and not just the ZeroTier connection but I guess I have to trhoubleshoot it with them.

Comment: Just for completion I wanted to mention that my router (OPNsense) is also in the same ZeroTier network so this might cause the issue. To sum it up, both the machine and the router are physically connected over LAN and over ZeroTier (I have the ZeroTier so I can access those devices remotely). Probably this combination is causing some kinds of issues.